# how to avoid document.write my below code

Tags: javascript, json

This code is working, but google pagespeed detect avoid `document.write`.

I've tested various alternatives, lining up my HTML elements prior to the `JS`, then using `getElementById`, followed by either `innerHTML` or `appendChild`, or even lining up the elements inside the `JS`, by means of `createElement`, but to no avail, really. maybe my tested was wrong.
Probably a factor as to why they're doing so poorly. I'm sure I couldn't sort the above codes correctly. I'm basically not experienced in JavaScript.

**Here is my CSS/HTML/JS inside this snipet code**:

```css
.cat-back {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
margin-top: 13px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 5px;
border-left: 3px solid #000
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both
}
.catcol {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.mbtlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden
}

.mbtlist li {
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
  clear: both;
  color: #666;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mbtlist .mbttitle {
  font-family: oswald;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mbtlist .mbttitle:hover {
  color: #00A5FF;
}

font-family:georgia;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold
}
.mbtlist div span {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mbtlist span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.mbtlist .imore {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 0.7em;
}
.mbtlist img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 65px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px #777;
}
.mbtlist .icontent {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script>
//----------------------------Defaults       
var ListBlogLink = window.location.hostname;
var ListCount = 5;
var TitleCount = 70;
var ListLabel = " ";
var ChrCount = 80;


var ImageSize = 100;


//----------------------------Function Start      
function mbtlist(json) {
  document.write('<ul class="mbtlist">');
  for (var i = 0; i < ListCount; i++) {

    //-----------------------------Variables Declared       
    var listing = ListUrl = ListTitle = ListConten = ListContent = ListImage = thumbUrl = sk = "";
    //----------------------------- Title URL       
    for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
      if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
        break;
      }
    }
    ListUrl = "'" + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + "'";
    //----------------------------------- Title Stirng       
    if (json.feed.entry[i].title != null) {
      ListTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t.substr(0, TitleCount);
    }


    //----------------------------------- Content Check

    ListConten = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
    ListContent = ListConten.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").substr(0, ChrCount);


    //------------------------------------ Thumbnail Check

    if (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail) {
      thumbUrl = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;


      sk = thumbUrl.replace("/s72-c/", "/s" + ImageSize + "/");
      ListImage = "'" + sk.replace("?imgmax=800", "") + "'";
    }

    // Support For 3rd Party Images      
    else if (json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/) != null) {
      ListImage = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1];
    } else {
      ListImage = "'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HALLtgFeep0/VfryhQ0C5oI/AAAAAAAAPcY/77mSGND4q84/s200/Icon.png'";
    }

    //----------------------------------- Printing List       
    var listing = "<li><a href=" +
      ListUrl +
      "><img src=" +
      ListImage +
      "/></a><a class='mbttitle' href=" +
      ListUrl +
      "target='_blank'>" +
      ListTitle +
      "</a><span class='icontent'>" +
      ListContent +
      " ...  <a href=" +
      ListUrl +
      " class='imore'>»</a></span></li>";
    document.write(listing);
  }
  document.write("</ul>");
}</script>
<div class='row'>
<div class='catcol'><div class='cat-back'><h3>Seba Top</h3></div></div>
  <script>
    ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org";
    ListCount = 4;
    TitleCount = 70;
    ListLabel = "seba-top";
    ChrCount = 150;

    document.write("<script src='" + ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + ListLabel + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist'></" + "script>");
  </script>
</div>

<div class='catcol'><div class='cat-back'><h3>Lead News</h3></div></div>
  <script>
    ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org";
    ListCount = 4;
    TitleCount = 70;
    ListLabel = "lead-news";
    ChrCount = 150;

    document.write("<script src='" + ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + ListLabel + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist'></" + "script>");
  </script>
</div>

<div class='catcol'><div class='cat-back'><h3>Top News</h3></div></div>
  <script>
    ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org";
    ListCount = 4;
    TitleCount = 70;
    ListLabel = "top-news";
    ChrCount = 150;

    document.write("<script src='" + ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + ListLabel + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist'></" + "script>");
  </script>
</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<div class='catcol'><div class='cat-back'><h3>জাতীয়</h3></div></div>
  <script>
    ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org";
    ListCount = 4;
    TitleCount = 70;
    ListLabel = "জাতীয়";
    ChrCount = 150;

    document.write("<script src='" + ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + ListLabel + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist'></" + "script>");
  </script>
</div>

<div class='catcol'><div class='cat-back'><h3>রাজনীতি</h3></div></div>
  <script>
    ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org";
    ListCount = 4;
    TitleCount = 70;
    ListLabel = "রাজনীতি";
    ChrCount = 150;

    document.write("<script src='" + ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + ListLabel + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist'></" + "script>");
  </script>
</div>

<div class='catcol'><div class='cat-back'><h3>বিশ্ব</h3></div></div>
  <script>
    ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org";
    ListCount = 4;
    TitleCount = 70;
    ListLabel = "বিশ্ব";
    ChrCount = 150;

    document.write("<script src='" + ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + ListLabel + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist'></" + "script>");
  </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Would it be possible for anyone to point me to the right direction?

Please solve this problem any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on new code I suggest this

```js
//----------------------------Defaults       
var ListBlogLink = "https://www.sebahotnews.org",
    ListCount = 4,
    TitleCount = 70,
    ChrCount = 150,
 ImageSize = 100;


const lists = [{"label":"seba-top" },{"label":"lead-news" },{"label":"top-news" }]
let cnt = 0;

function next() {
  if (cnt>=lists.length) return
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += `<div class='catcol ${lists[cnt].label}'></div>`
  const scr = document.createElement("script");
  scr.src = ListBlogLink + "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + lists[cnt].label + "?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist";
  document.querySelector("head").appendChild(scr);
};  

next(); // start


function mbtlist(json) {
  let div = document.querySelector("#container ."+lists[cnt].label);
  let html = '<ul class="mbtlist">';
  for (var i = 0; i < ListCount; i++) {

    //-----------------------------Variables Declared       
    var listing = ListUrl = ListTitle = ListConten = ListContent = ListImage = thumbUrl = sk = "";
    //----------------------------- Title URL       
    for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
      if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
        break;
      }
    }
    ListUrl = "'" + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + "'";
    //----------------------------------- Title Stirng       
    if (json.feed.entry[i].title != null) {
      ListTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t.substr(0, TitleCount);
    }


    //----------------------------------- Content Check

    ListConten = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
    ListContent = ListConten.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").substr(0, ChrCount);


    //------------------------------------ Thumbnail Check

    if (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail) {
      thumbUrl = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;


      sk = thumbUrl.replace("/s72-c/", "/s" + ImageSize + "/");
      ListImage = "'" + sk.replace("?imgmax=800", "") + "'";
    }

    // Support For 3rd Party Images      
    else if (json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/) != null) {
      ListImage = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1];
    } else {
      ListImage = "'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HALLtgFeep0/VfryhQ0C5oI/AAAAAAAAPcY/77mSGND4q84/s200/Icon.png'";
    }

    //----------------------------------- Printing List       
    var listing = "<li><a href=" +
      ListUrl +
      "><img src=" +
      ListImage +
      "/></a><a class='mbttitle' href=" +
      ListUrl +
      "target='_blank'>" +
      ListTitle +
      "</a><span class='icontent'>" +
      ListContent +
      " ...  <a href=" +
      ListUrl +
      " class='imore'>»</a></span></li>";
    html += listing;
  }
  html += "</ul>";
  div.innerHTML = html;
  cnt++;  
  next(); // call next 
}
```

```css
.seba-top { background-color:orange;}
.top-news { background-color:tan;}
.lead-news { background-color:yellow;}
.catcol {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mbtlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden
}

.mbtlist li {
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
  clear: both;
  color: #666;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mbtlist .mbttitle {
  font-family: oswald;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mbtlist .mbttitle:hover {
  color: #00A5FF;
}

font-family:georgia;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold
}
.mbtlist div span {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mbtlist span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.mbtlist .imore {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 0.7em;
}
.mbtlist img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 65px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px #777;
}
.mbtlist .icontent {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Any console errors? The code works if you add a div with id container or rename my container to match yours

Comment: yes your code is working, but when i used your code another all label, then not working. that's why  i did update my code. check it

Comment: i need your help.

Comment: I gave all the help I want to give here. Your question was answered and then you changed it

Comment: i need your help. https://www.sebahotnews.org this is my site. you can browse and see how i arranged my site. there is a problem, when reload my site after create a post, then total post will reload.  i saw another site when reload, there only load updated post. then i searched google for solution, there i find document.write is a problem. I need Your Help. I'm basically not experienced in JavaScript.

Comment: In fact, 50 euros and much less, the more you help, the more it costs. But I can't afford it. I have no way to send you money abroad. But thank you so much for all the help you have given. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I can't make any such income from my website, if I could make an income, of course I could pay your price.

Comment: I was joking. I’m really not going to spend another hour fixing a script I already fixed once

Comment: Dhannabad Bondhu.

Comment: I do not see my script on your page at all

Comment: your code coming with three column together in one div. i cant give any name these columns. i have give three name for three column. that's why i updated my code upper. for your understanding.

Comment: You can use css and flex to move the columns

Comment: .catcol is a column class

Comment: I did not modify your columns except giving them a colour for you to see

Comment: i know you gave right direction with your code, but maybe i don't understand. i will try my best with your code. all over your code is very useful. thank you.